# A pentagon with labeled edges

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have the following code for a pentagon to be generated using tikz. I'm trying to modify the code slightly, but I haven't been able to progress any further. I would like for the "dots" at the vertices to go away, so as to show only straight lines, and for the numbers inside of the pentagon to be a little neater, but I haven't been able to shift them, either.

Thanks.

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\foreach \a in {5}{
\node[regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, minimum size=3cm, draw] at (\a*4,0) (A) {};
\foreach \i in {1,...,\a}
    \node[circle, label=above:\i, fill=black, inner sep=1pt] at (A.corner \i) {};
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

Comment: Remove the `fill=black` statement and the dots will vanish.

Answer (score 10):

Something like this?

[image: labelled pentagon]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt,tikz,multi]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \foreach \a in {5}{
    \node [regular polygon, regular polygon sides=\a, minimum size=3cm, draw] at (\a*4,0) (A) {};
    \foreach \i in {1,...,\a}
    {%
      \node [label=90+72*(\i-1):\i, inner sep=1pt] at (A.corner \i) {};
    }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to change the line width? for example 0.8mm.

Comment: @ryuk Add `line width=0.8mm`?

Comment: yes, increase the line thickness

Comment: Then just add the key-value option I gave above to whatever you want to have thicker lines.