# Pentagon symbol

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols

Is there a pentagon symbol? Alternatively, is there some way I can use a the output of tikz, shrink it down and make it into a symbol? Then I could use this and just remove the labels: [A pentagon with labeled edges](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/305448/a-pentagon-with-labeled-edges)

Comment: Your link shows that there is a *shape* for a regular polygon with five sides aka a pentagon. What do you mean with “symbol”?

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel A symbol I can use in mathematical text, like $\triangle$ or $\square$. My thought was "can I shrink down that shape and use it as a symbol?"

Comment: You can look up symbols on [Detexify](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/21/16595), it also gives you the package to use. Besides that, any TikZ picture can be made in a symbol by just defining a macro for the picture. If you use it extensively it might be worth it to save it in a savebox and use that down the line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this?

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}
\pentagon
\end{document}
```

[image]

```
%% Compile and read me!
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{stix}
\begin{document}
\Huge{$\pentagon$}
\end{document}
```

[image]